# Exporting cv2.selectROI data to JSON, python 3.6

Tags: python, opencv

I want to export the coordinates from cv2.selectROI function to a JSONlike file so I could use them in another python script. The code that I have is:

```
 r = cv2.selectROI(img, fromCenter)
print(r)
with open('data.txt','w') as outf:
    json.dump({r},outf, indent=4)
```

and the error I get looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
(474, 363, 89, 233)
  File "C:/Users/razvanv/PycharmProjects/opencv/SpotDetectionFunction.py", line 51, in <module>
    f(parcare)
  File "C:/Users/razvanv/PycharmProjects/opencv/SpotDetectionFunction.py", line 16, in f
    json.dump({r},outf, indent=4)
  File "C:\Users\razvanv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\razvanv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 437, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Users\razvanv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable
```

Do you have any solution to export this coordinates?
Thank you!

Comment: Just remove the curly braces `{ }` from `r` on the `json.dump()` call. Besides being redundant, as `r` is a tuple already, the error you're getting is informing you that sets don't work in this situation, and the curly braces are transforming `r` into a set.

Comment: It worked, thank you @Gabriel!